# Can one still redeem Wii Points in the Wii Shop Channel after discontinuation?

Tags: nintendo-wii, club-nintendo

With the closing of [WiiConnect24](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3512/p/604), [Nintendo WiFi Connection](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/info/en_na/services-update.jsp), and now even [Club Nintendo](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/13913/p/52), is it still possible to add Wii Points and buy WiiWare and other software in the Shop Channel?

Comment: It is very unlikely that the Wii eShop will be going off any time soon as it can be used within the WiiU's Wii menu.

Comment: @Powerlord Although it probably comes from the same source, the [Wii Shop Channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_Shop_Channel) and the [Nintendo eShop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nintendo_eShop) are actually two different stores. What I mean is, Shop Channel uses Nintendo Points purchased with real money, and eShop uses real money directly. Unless you meant something else, I think that the "Wii eShop" is not possible for the original Wii. Of course, this is beside the point, but I'm *trying* to eliminate confusion!

Comment: The WiiU has access to both shops.  The eShop is accessible from the main menu, while the Wii Shop Channel is accessible from within Wii mode (which is itself on the main menu).  (Admittedly, eShop was a braino on my part in the original comment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still possible to purchase Wii Points and DSi Points at this current time.  Most point cards are off the market though it seems, with the only way to buy them is to visit the shop channels directly and use a credit/debit card.

---

Side note:  I cannot find any information online on Nintendo's website to suggest that the Wii/DSi point system is going offline anytime soon.  I have bought points recently.  (Picture of points purchase on the new Store and previous store, as by Mint records.)

[image]

Comment: So, if Nintendo decides to stop the Shop for the Wii, what would happen to the software you can buy? Would it then become *free*? :-D

Comment: I would hope so, but most companies are not that generous. :(  Best case is that the software gets ported over, worst case is that it's lost forever.

Comment: The DSi shop has since [closed down](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/16880/~/service-discontinuation%3A-nintendo-dsi-shop-%28updated-3%2F31%2F17%29) on 3/31/2017.

Answer (score 2):

No, you will not be able to continue to redeem Wii Points once the Wii Shop Channel is discontinued, per the [official closure announcement](https://www.nintendo.com/whatsnew/detail/wii-shop-closure-announcement) from Nintendo.

The Wii Shop Channel will be closing down on January 30, 2019.  Wii Points can continue to be added until March 26, 2018, and content can be purchased with existing points through January 30, 2019.

Nintendo has provided [a Q&A](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/27560/p/604) with additional details.